# Numpy / Scipy not writing to certain pixels

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to use numpy and scipy to create a png image, then colour each pixel individually. However, when I choose the size, 255 x 255, and try to change the pixel at the x,y coordinate 255,255, it says it's out of range.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.misc as smp
from PIL import Image

data = np.zeros( (255,255), dtype = np.uint8)
data[255,255] = [0,0,0] # Attempt to set a black pixel
data[0,0] = [255,0,0] # Attempt to set a red pixel
img = Image.fromarray(data)
img.save("Test.png","PNG")
```

But, I get this following error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\***\***\***\***\***.py", line 8, in <module>
    data[255,255] = [255,0,255]
IndexError: index 255 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 255
```

I would appreciate any help or suggestion, thanks.

Comment: NumPy indexing (just like Python indexing) is zero-based.  If the size is 255, the indices range from 0 to 254.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser You will not believe how hard I just face-palmed. Thank you for not giving a condescending based upon my idiocy... Maybe put that as answer so I can accept it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NumPy indexing (just like Python indexing) is zero-based. If the size is 255, the indices range from 0 to 254.

- Thankyou to Warren Wecknesser